# Enable history on pre-existing custom archetype

Tags: plone, archetypes

I have a custom archetype content type that I have enabled history for. Content that I now add has history, and accessing the @@history view works as intended

However content that existed before I enabled history throws an error when trying to access the same view. This is the error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
    Module Products.CMFEditions.browser.diff, line 48, in __call__

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'retrieve'
```

It doesn't matter how many times I have subsequently edited the content, and I've tried copy/cut and paste, I still get the above error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The history-view used to be a skin-template, now is a browser-view. The skin-template has been removed with vs. 2.2.10 of Products.CMFEditions. Maybe your old AT's are still looking for the skin-template. You could give it a try, downgrade to 2.2.9 and see, if the error still occurs.

Comment: Correction: Not the template has been removed, but the old skins- python-script `getVersionDiff.py`, which it's calling. Comparing that one with the new browser-script, could be worth to have a look.

Comment: Are you doing an edit-proper or are you just hitting edit and then save? The event handler does not create a version if it thinks the content has not changed after all.

Comment: I did a proper edit – added spaces, full stops, words etc. I've actially fixed the issue in a round about sort of way that involved hacking code in the egg to initialise the history. Once initialised this won't be a problem again.